# What data type do I use for an integer in SOAP XML in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa, cocoa-touch, soap

I imagine it is just an int, but I want to verify.

Thanks
Corey

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, just an int.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using NSInteger/NSUInteger instead of int. NS(U)Integer maps to the appropriate size based on the environment you are running in. It might not matter much for the current iPhones/iPods, but you might as well future proof your code. See [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUInteger) for further discussion.